# gcc print warnings without compile

Tags: gcc, lint

I'd like gcc to do source code analysis for errors, but do not write any output files (similarly to what splint does).
I've found this solution currently:

```
gcc -Wall -c source.c > NUL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could redirect the output to `/dev/null`

```
gcc -o /dev/null ...
```

Answer (score 8):

There is `-fsyntax-only` option, which means exactly what you want:

> "Check the code for syntax errors, but don’t do
>   anything beyond that."

This option bit more portable between OSes than using `/dev/null` or `NUL` as output.

This option is also supported by clang C/C++/ObjC frontend, which is used with LLVM: `clang-3.1 -fsyntax-only`.

Update: But you should know that some warnings are generated not by syntax parser, but by internal compiler phases. For example, syntax parser can't detect full control flow (only optimizer will) and some warnings like "control reaches end of non-void function" will not be generated in `-fsyntax-only` option.

Comment: this way it prints a lot of unuseful warnings:  "linker input file unused because linking not done"

Comment: Actually it will not print this, if used correctly (Put fsyntax-only only to CFLAGS, not to LDFLAGS). But I just noticed that -fsyntax-only gives less warnings than `-c` (In my case - "control reaches end of non-void function")